# Bot to reply to a part of a message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'good morning!')
msg.reply('morning!');
 }
 );
```

---

This command works when I say "good morning!", but what would the code be if I wanted it to reply to something like "I just woke up, good morning!" And I do not mean that exactly, I just mean if the trigger message is in the middle of another message

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`String.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) function, which will return a `boolean` whether a string includes the given argument.

```js
const message = 'Happy Birthday Random Person!';
const otherMessage = 'Happy Birthday Person I Know!';

if (message.toLowerCase().includes('random person'))
  console.log("You shouldn't be talking to random people on the internet >:(");
  
if (otherMessage.toLowerCase().includes('random person'))
  console.log("You shouldn't be talking to random people on the internet >:(");
else console.log('Good, you were being safe ༼ つ ◕_◕ ༽つ')
```

```js
if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes('good morning')) {
  // do stuff
};
```